# SQLite, is there better way to inner join?

Tags: sql, sqlite, inner-join

I am trying to inner join two tables with conditions

For ex. I want to find member information with course join date/time in certain interval of join date/time.

There are two tables, member and course

```
SELECT m.firstname, m.lastname, c.join_date, c.join_time, c.courseID
FROM member AS m 
     JOIN course c 
          ON m.firstname = c.firstname AND
             m.lastname = c.lastname
WHERE c.join_date >= 20170501 AND (yyyymmdd format)
      c.join_time >= 130500 (hhmmss format)
```

Is there any efficient or better way to achieve same goal?

Comment: Unrelated, but I'm not sure your WHERE clause is doing what you want it to do. It will fail to match, for example, time `130459` on date `20170502`.

Comment: Is there an ID in your member table that you can join on? The only major problem I see is that if you have two people with the same First & Last name you will get dupes. And you probably only need to filter on the join_date column and not join_time.

Comment: Also remember joins are faster if the FK fields are indexed.